# Execute commands after section

Tags: sectioning, context

How to execute code after or at the end of a section (or subsection, chapter, etc.)? I'm looking for a more elegant solution than this:

```
\definehead[mysectionImpl][section]
\let\startmysection\startmysectionImpl
\def\stopmysection{\stopmysectionImpl\DOWHATEVER}
```

Comment: The problem is `\section` is merely a command to create a header (plus `toc` info, etc.)  It is not an environment.  It has no knowledge of what comes after and thus has no way to know when a "section" ends.

Comment: It's not quite clear from your example, what you are trying to do, but have you checked `after` and `aftersection` in the setups? Like: `\definehead[mysectionImpl][section] \setuphead[mysectionImpl][after=\DOWHATEVER]`, cf. https://www.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead

Comment: I have checked `after` but I couldn't find `aftersection`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - I believe the OP is using ConTeXt, not LaTeX. Unlike LaTeX, Context features `\startsection` and `\stopsection` directives.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for that useful bit of info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the start/stop form of a section command you can use the `aftersection` key of `\setuphead` to place something at the end of the section.

While you can pass your command as argument to `aftersection` it is often cleaner to put the commands in a `setups` environment and load the environment instead.

```
\startsetups[section:after]
    \blank[samepage,line]
    \midaligned{\symbol[diamond]}
\stopsetups

\setuphead
  [section]
  [aftersection=\directsetup{section:after}]

\starttext

\startsection[title=Knuth]
\samplefile{knuth}
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I know that you are just illustrating a point with the example, but in case someone decides to use this as is, `\blank[samepage]` is better as it avoids a pagebreak between the end of section and end of section marker.